# Laravel Own model for users on request property in middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

In middleware we can access laravel's user model which comes with laravel via

```
if($request->User() === null)
        {
            echo 10000;
        }
```

But I have my own models, and own table of Users.
My model is `Users` not `User`

When I try to do:

```
if($request->Users() === null)
        {
            echo 10000;
        }
```

I get this error:

[image]

How do I attach my own Users model to the request?
Instead of using the already built in User?

Comment: in `config/auth` you can change the model responsible.

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload`